# how to get users imdb profile and then import to an online app

Tags: imdb

Am building an app that film expert can use to connect with one another but i want them to be able to import their profile from IMDB, in order to set their profile on the app.

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://malhar2010.blogspot.com.tr/2011/02/using-imdb-api-to-get-details-of-movie.html) can be helpfull for you. You can implement other functionality with this way.